# iphone SDK 4 Grouped TableViewCell double border on top

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Perhaps it's very simple but I can't figure it out.

I have a custom TableviewCell. I'm using iPhone SDK 4. I am creating just one row in table view (Grouped) but sadly that table view has double border on top and all other sides have normal single border. I must say that I noticed that when upgraded to Xcode 3.2.3 and iPhone SDK 4. This is what I am getting on iphone...

[alt text http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/9818/img0056k.png](http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/9818/img0056k.png)

Does any know what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some code from your cell, and how you set up your table view? A screenshot could be useful, too.

Comment: Hi, I'm on the move at the moment. Can you please wait untill tomorrow so I could get access to my computer. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have updated the original question with a screenshot. Any thoughts?

Comment: I would be more worried about the background.

Comment: Believe me it's not the background. I have similar background on another view and that table view cell is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 4):

Check the settings of the tableView in Interface Builder...
Find the **Separator attribute**... By default it is set to **Single Line Etched** if you are using a grouped table view.
Change this attribute to **Single Line** or **None** to resolve your problem... ;)

However if you are creating the table view programmatically, without Interface Builder, you can resolve adding this line of code in a method like **viewDidLoad**:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone; 
or  
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
```

Hope can help you!

Regards,
Matteo

Comment: I insisted on     self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor]; and it did not really help +1 for this advice